# package not install in pycharm

Tags: python, zorin, ide

I am using Zorin os 16.1 pros. I am trying to install pyaudio in pycharm it gives an error. But it is already installed in the terminal. I don't know where it is installed. It gives

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on Linux
```

when typing python3 -v in the terminal. pycharm python version 3.10. My problem is similar to this.

Comment: You say you get an error? When you do what? What is the error? What is the command?